# How to execute actions before MapReduce job starts using JobControl

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've got JobControl that controls chain of n jobs.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        Job eStep = EStepJob.createJob(config);
        Job mStep = MStepJob.createJob(config);
        emChain.add(new ControlledJob(eStep, getDeps(emChain)));
        emChain.add(new ControlledJob(mStep, getDeps(emChain)));
    }
    jobControl.addJobCollection(emChain);
```

I would like to clean output directories only and only before each job starts;
But the directories must not be cleaned at the time the jobs initialized.
My current solution is to place clearing code into map phase, thats drastically slows the execution.

```
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());
        if (fs.exists(new Path(context.getConfiguration().get(
                AR_PROBS_OUTPUT)))) {
            fs.delete(
                    new Path(context.getConfiguration()
                            .get(AR_PROBS_OUTPUT)), true);
        }
```

Are there any more adequate methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Mapper.setup()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html#setup(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context)) method for the same. It is a method that is executed before any map task is started at any node.
I believe you are using HDFS when you initialize the FileSystem in your code.

Anyway the code should work the same way. But the number of times it gets executed will be equal to the number of Mapper Tasks generated and not the number of times each Mapper task gets executed!

Answer (score 1):

You can store output into temporary directory when you initialise the job.
After the job completion you can remove temporary directory.

Then you can check, is output need to commit? If yes, then using OutputCommitter you can commit the output.

Please check below link:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/OutputCommitter.html